# Basic Python question: referencing original variable inside for loop?

Tags: python

Quick, newbie Python scoping question. How can I make sure that the *original* variables get changed in the for-loop below?

```
for name in [name_level_1, name_level_2, name_level_3, name_level_4]:
     name = util.translate("iw", "en", name.encode('utf-8'))
print name_level_1
```

In other words, I want the `print` statement to print out the changed variable, not the original. Python doesn't have pointers, right?

Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that you aren't changing anything, aren't you?

Comment: Presumably the OP has names in different encodings. And of course that's what the question is about -- how to make the changes efficacious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has references and objects instead of pointers (from a conceptual level).

What you want to do is assign the new value of name_level_1 to some name that exists after the loop.

So, either unwrap the loop and use each name where you need it, e.g.

```
name_level_1_translated = util.translate("iw", "en", name_level_1.encode('utf-8'))
print name_level_1_translated

name_level_2_translated = util.translate("iw", "en", name_level_2.encode('utf-8'))
do_stuff(name_level_2_translated)
```

or, if you're going to use each name the same way, just create a list and use that everywhere.

```
names = [name_level_1, name_level_2, name_level_3, name_level_4]
translated_names = [util.translate("iw", "en", name.encode('utf-8')) for name in names]
for name in translated_names:
    print name
```

You can also access them by index:

```
print names[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do what you want to do.

To do something similar you can use indexing into the array:

```
names = [name_level_1, name_level_2, name_level_3, name_level_4]
for i in range(len(names)):
     names[i] = util.translate("iw", "en", names[i].encode('utf-8'))
print names[0]
```

But normally for this sort of thing you would just use a list comprehension:

```
names = [name_level_1, name_level_2, name_level_3, name_level_4]
names = [util.translate("iw", "en", name.encode('utf-8')) for name in names]
```

Answer (score 0):

make name_level_1 an object:

```
class LevelOne(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.x = 3

name_level_1 = LevelOne()
count = 0
for name in [name_level_1, LevelOne(), LevelOne()]:
    name.x = count

print name_level_1.x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the names in the global namespace using `globals()`:

```
for name,value in globals().items():
    if name.startswith("name_level_"):
        globals()[name] = util.translate("iw", "en", value.encode('utf-8'))
```

However, storing the names in an array or dict is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid polluting your namespace with lots of related variables, group them together in a dictionary or a list. e.g.

```
NAMES = { 'level_1': 'something', 'level_2': 'something else',
    'level_3': 'whatever', 'level_4': 'and so on' }
for name in NAMES:
     NAMES[name] = util.translate("iw", "en", NAMES[name].encode('utf-8'))
print NAMES['level_1']
```